# CKAN site logo change

Tags: ckan

I want to change the default CKAN site logo using the Administrator Config panel. However every time I click Submit, /uploads/admin is prepended to the logo path resulting in a resource not found. How can I disable the prepend behaviour, or otherwise set the correct logo path?

EDIT: For anyone else having the same problem I found a solution, modifying the CKAN source update.py, which by default prepends /uploads/admin if the link doesn't start with http. Can also modify the jinja template config.html to allow non urls

Comment: Is this error just with this version? Is there an explanation for this problem?

Comment: Is the problem solved? I'm having the same problem. I'm trying the latest master branch.

Comment: I mean by not modifying ckan source. I am running it with `docker-compose`.